# Bind map and list in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(StressTest stressTest) {
    //dosomething
    return "ok";
}
```

Bind Class:

```
Class StressTest {
    private Map<String,List<String>> methods;
    private String serviceName;
    ...
}
```

Question is:
How to write html form,my http post package :

```
methods['GetSome'].[0].value=ds&methods['GetSome'].[1].value=asaaaaa&serviceName=aa
```

But bind fail in springmvc,List in methods always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted data are not correct. Get rid of the *.value* part

Try to produce this:

```
methods['GetSome'].[0]=ds&methods['GetSome'].[1]=asaaaaa&serviceName=aa
```

Comment: Doesn't work...When spring parse [0],it throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use methods['GetSome'][0]=ds. If use List ,use methods['GetSome'][0].someMember.